# Firebase: No properties to serialise - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running into problems trying to read and write data to/from my Firebase realtime database. I have a register and login activity. When I register a user, I want to authenticate them and add the User's data to the database.

Here is my User class:

```
  public class myUser {

public static boolean onlineStatus;
public static int userAge;
public static String userGender;
public static String userId;
public static String userName;

public myUser() {

}
//Default constructor will have/set the default info for the users such as:
//(auto generated) id name, age, and gender initialised at creation time


public myUser(boolean onlineStatus, int userAge, String userGender, String userId, String userName ) {

    this.onlineStatus = onlineStatus;
    this.userAge = userAge;
    this.userGender = userGender;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;

}


//Getters
public static String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public static String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public static int getUserAge() {
    return userAge;
}

public static String getUserGender() {
    return userGender;
}

public static boolean getOnlineStatus() {
    return onlineStatus;
}

//Setters
public static void setOnlineStatusTrue() {
    onlineStatus = true;
}

public static void setOnlineStatusFalse() {
    onlineStatus = false;
}

}
```

Now when I set a Database reference to my User object like so:

```
String id = databaseUsers.push().getKey();

myUser userRef = new myUser(onlineStatus, age, gender, id, name );

databaseUsers.setValue(userRef);
```

Now when I go register a user in my register activity my App crashes and I get the following error:

No properties to serialise:
(https://puu.sh/A08NT.png

I've also added some ProGuard rules but I still get the same error.

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class com.example.teamc.friendfinder.** {
  *;
}
```

All I would like to do is to register a user, add them to the database and set their online status to False. Then when the user signs in I'd like to set it to True so I'm able to get their online status activity and update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, please use the following steps.

1. Change all your fileds from your model class from `public static` to `private`.

   ```
   private boolean onlineStatus;
   private int userAge;
   private String userGender;
   private String userId;
   private String userName;
   ```
2. Change all your setters and getters from your model class from `public static` to only `public`.